# Loop cuts, creases or bevels?

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

I'm still trying to figure out how to keep meshes simple. I'm trying to use a sub surf to create my model, see attached. Figuring out how to insert proximity loops without inserting masses of geometry (or loops that create  more detail where I don't want it) isn't going well.

I've tried loop cuts, bevels and creases to make the sub serf result look more like the plain model, but I feel like what I'm doing is a bodge, not good workflow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still sounds like an use case for creases with which you can guide the Subdivision  Surface modifier. Basically you are telling the modifier which parts of the geometry should not "move away" under deformation, so you need to crease every edge defining your shape. Take a look at for the J, from your description i believe this is what you're after:
[image]

Comment: Thanks taiyo, this is a big help — you've creased areas I didn't (I'm struggling to understand the crease tool, getting a lot of unwanted shapes...). I had tried using a bevel weight, but I didn't feel I had as much control. This seems a lot more flexible, thank you!